# When does Apache creates new processes?

Tags: linux, debian, apache-2.2

We have a situation - we have a lot of webapps on the server and some cron jobs. We are suspecting that perhaps one of the cron jobs is causing growth of number of apache processes.

I know Apache creates processes for new visitors to be able to handle their requests in parallel, but are there any other situations, when Apache creates new processes?

Actually we cannot discover, which of the jobs is it. How to debug it in real-time, or check back in history, which of script of "webapp", or user (of database) has overloaded the server?

Are there any useful tools for that?

Comment: Which mpm module are you running? single or multi-cpu system?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you suspect a cron job is causing the additional Apache requests, you should be able to monitor/grep the default Apache access log (/var/log/apache2/access.log).

Also, double check your Apache config for the settings you're using. If you haven't made any modifications to the default config, then it is likely you're using the Prefork MPM, and you can find your current settings in /etc/apache2/apache2.conf.